Getting deasync error when trying to install yarn dependencies
error C:\FOLDER\FOLDER\automatarium\node_modules\deasync: Command failed.
Exit code: 1
Command: node ./build.js
Arguments:
Directory: C:\FOLDER\FOLDER\automatarium\node_modules\deasync
Output:
node:internal/child_process:421
    throw new ErrnoException(err, 'spawn');
    ^

Error: spawn EINVAL
    at ChildProcess.spawn (node:internal/child_process:421:11)
    at Object.spawn (node:child_process:761:9)
    at build (C:\FOLDER\FOLDER\automatarium\node_modules\deasync\build.js:77:6)
    at Object.<anonymous> (C:\FOLDER\FOLDER\automatarium\node_modules\deasync\build.js:69:5)
    at Module._compile (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1368:14)
    at Module._extensions..js (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1426:10)
    at Module.load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1205:32)
    at Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1021:12)
    at Function.executeUserEntryPoint [as runMain] (node:internal/modules/run_main:142:12)
    at node:internal/main/run_main_module:28:49 {
  errno: -4071,
  code: 'EINVAL',
  syscall: 'spawn'

Attempted to run yarn install in root directory of repo. Works on other devices but on mine simply fails with above error message.

Sounds like https://github.com/abbr/deasync/issues/106

The only thing that worked for me was downgrading node:
$ brew uninstall node@22
$ brew install node@20 

